# Error (IllegalStateException) when converting vaadin 24.2.7 to 24.3.2

Tags: vaadin

I wanted to switch from vaadin 24.2.7 to vaadin 24.3.2 and get the following error during build:

IntelliJ IDEA 2023.3.2 (Community Edition)
How can I find the error? Everything works under 24.2.7.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Vite process exited with non-zero exit code.
Stderr: 'vite v5.0.6 building for production...
transforming...
✓ 211 modules transformed.
Expression expected (Note that you need plugins to import files that are not JavaScript)
file: /home/ubuntu/IdeaProjects/pverein/node_modules/@vaadin-component-factory/vcf-nav/src/vcf-nav.ts:13:0
11: let id = 0;
12: 
13: @customElement('vcf-nav')
    ^
14: export class Nav extends LitElement {
15:   @property({ type: Boolean, reflect: true })
error during build:
RollupError: Expression expected
    at error (file:///home/ubuntu/IdeaProjects/pverein/node_modules/vite/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/parseAst.js:337:30)
    at nodeConverters (file:///home/ubuntu/IdeaProjects/pverein/node_modules/vite/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/parseAst.js:2084:9)
    at convertNode (file:///home/ubuntu/IdeaProjects/pverein/node_modules/vite/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/parseAst.js:969:12)
    at convertProgram (file:///home/ubuntu/IdeaProjects/pverein/node_modules/vite/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/parseAst.js:960:48)
    at parseAstAsync (file:///home/ubuntu/IdeaProjects/pverein/node_modules/vite/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/parseAst.js:2150:20)
    at async Module.tryParseAsync (file:///home/ubuntu/IdeaProjects/pverein/node_modules/vite/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:13513:21)
    at async Module.setSource (file:///home/ubuntu/IdeaProjects/pverein/node_modules/vite/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:13094:35)
    at async ModuleLoader.addModuleSource (file:///home/ubuntu/IdeaProjects/pverein/node_modules/vite/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:17757:13)
'
    at com.vaadin.flow.plugin.base.BuildFrontendUtil.runFrontendBuildTool (BuildFrontendUtil.java:488)
    at com.vaadin.flow.plugin.base.BuildFrontendUtil.runVite (BuildFrontendUtil.java:442)
    at com.vaadin.flow.plugin.base.BuildFrontendUtil.runFrontendBuild (BuildFrontendUtil.java:425)
    at com.vaadin.flow.plugin.maven.BuildFrontendMojo.execute (BuildFrontendMojo.java:138)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:126)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:328)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:316)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:174)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.access$000 (MojoExecutor.java:75)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor$1.run (MojoExecutor.java:162)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.execute (DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.java:39)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:159)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:73)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:118)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:261)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:173)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:906)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:283)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:206)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:568)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:283)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:226)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:407)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:348)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:47)
Caused by: org.zeroturnaround.exec.InvalidExitValueException: Unexpected exit value: 1, allowed exit values: [0], executed command [/usr/bin/node, /home/ubuntu/IdeaProjects/pverein/node_modules/vite/bin/vite.js, build] in directory /home/ubuntu/IdeaProjects/pverein with environment {PATH=/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/snap/bin, INVOCATION_ID=9b5a8a1bc23a48d5bdaaec3a90ee32f8, XAUTHORITY=/run/user/1000/.mutter-Xwaylandauth.4XT9F2, LC_MEASUREMENT=de_DE.UTF-8, LC_TELEPHONE=de_DE.UTF-8, XMODIFIERS=@im=ibus, GDMSESSION=ubuntu, XDG_DATA_DIRS=/usr/share/ubuntu:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/:/var/lib/snapd/desktop, LC_TIME=de_DE.UTF-8, SNAP_COMMON=/var/snap/intellij-idea-community/common, PAPERSIZE=a4, SNAP_INSTANCE_KEY=, DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus, SNAP_USER_COMMON=/home/ubuntu/snap/intellij-idea-community/common, SNAP_REVISION=475, XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=ubuntu:GNOME, JOURNAL_STREAM=8:41257, USERNAME=ubuntu, SESSION_MANAGER=local/ubuntu-virtual-machine:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/1226,unix/ubuntu-virtual-machine:/tmp/.ICE-unix/1226, LC_PAPER=de_DE.UTF-8, LOGNAME=ubuntu, MANAGERPID=1061, PWD=/home/ubuntu/IdeaProjects/pverein, SNAP_UID=1000, IM_CONFIG_PHASE=1, LANGUAGE=de_DE:en, GJS_DEBUG_TOPICS=JS ERROR;JS LOG, SHELL=/bin/bash, LC_ADDRESS=de_DE.UTF-8, GIO_LAUNCHED_DESKTOP_FILE=/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/intellij-idea-community_intellij-idea-community.desktop, BAMF_DESKTOP_FILE_HINT=/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/intellij-idea-community_intellij-idea-community.desktop, GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID=this-is-deprecated, GTK_MODULES=gail:atk-bridge, SNAP_ARCH=amd64, SYSTEMD_EXEC_PID=1286, SNAP_LIBRARY_PATH=/var/lib/snapd/lib/gl:/var/lib/snapd/lib/gl32:/var/lib/snapd/void, GNOME_SETUP_DISPLAY=:1, XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP=ubuntu, SSH_AGENT_LAUNCHER=gnome-keyring, SHLVL=0, LC_IDENTIFICATION=de_DE.UTF-8, SNAP_EUID=1000, LC_MONETARY=de_DE.UTF-8, SNAP_NAME=intellij-idea-community, QT_IM_MODULE=ibus, XDG_CONFIG_DIRS=/etc/xdg/xdg-ubuntu:/etc/xdg, SNAP_INSTANCE_NAME=intellij-idea-community, LANG=de_DE.UTF-8, XDG_SESSION_TYPE=wayland, SNAP_USER_DATA=/home/ubuntu/snap/intellij-idea-community/475, DISPLAY=:0, WAYLAND_DISPLAY=wayland-0, SNAP_REEXEC=, SNAP_VERSION=2023.3.2, LC_NAME=de_DE.UTF-8, _=/usr/bin/gnome-session, XDG_SESSION_CLASS=user, SNAP_DATA=/var/snap/intellij-idea-community/475, DESKTOP_SESSION=ubuntu, USER=ubuntu, SNAP=/snap/intellij-idea-community/475, XDG_MENU_PREFIX=gnome-, SNAP_REAL_HOME=/home/ubuntu, GIO_LAUNCHED_DESKTOP_FILE_PID=3150, QT_ACCESSIBILITY=1, GJS_DEBUG_OUTPUT=stderr, LC_NUMERIC=de_DE.UTF-8, SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh, GNOME_SHELL_SESSION_MODE=ubuntu, SNAP_CONTEXT=WtywGOW4zl9_VX6yQYzFCwPMYcwXFdMAtMOK5prKJOsERkGaAszU, XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000, HOME=/home/ubuntu, SNAP_COOKIE=WtywGOW4zl9_VX6yQYzFCwPMYcwXFdMAtMOK5prKJOsERkGaAszU}, output was 1618 bytes:
vite v5.0.6 building for production...
transforming...
✓ 211 modules transformed.
Expression expected (Note that you need plugins to import files that are not JavaScript)
file: /home/ubuntu/IdeaProjects/pverein/node_modules/@vaadin-component-factory/vcf-nav/src/vcf-nav.ts:13:0
11: let id = 0;
12: 
13: @customElement('vcf-nav')
    ^
14: export class Nav extends LitElement {
15:   @property({ type: Boolean, reflect: true })
error during build:
RollupError: Expression expected
    at error (file:///home/ubuntu/IdeaProjects/pverein/node_modules/vite/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/parseAst.js:337:30)
    at nodeConverters (file:///home/ubuntu/IdeaProjects/pverein/node_modules/vite/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/parseAst.js:2084:9)
    at convertNode (file:///home/ubuntu/IdeaProjects/pverein/node_modules/vite/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/parseAst.js:969:12)
    at convertProgram (file:///home/ubuntu/IdeaProjects/pverein/node_modules/vite/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/parseAst.js:960:48)
    at parseAstAsync (file:///home/ubuntu/IdeaProjects/pverein/node_modules/vite/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/parseAst.js:2150:20)
    at async Module.tryParseAsync (file:///home/ubuntu/IdeaProjects/pverein/node_modules/vite/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:13513:21)
    at async Module.setSource (file:///home/ubuntu/IdeaProjects/pverein/node_modules/vite/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:13094:35)
    at async ModuleLoader.addModuleSource (file:///home/ubuntu/IdeaProjects/pverein/node_modules/vite/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:17757:13)
    at org.zeroturnaround.exec.InvalidExitUtil.checkExit (InvalidExitUtil.java:27)
    at org.zeroturnaround.exec.WaitForProcess.call (WaitForProcess.java:114)
    at org.zeroturnaround.exec.ProcessExecutor.waitFor (ProcessExecutor.java:1076)
    at org.zeroturnaround.exec.ProcessExecutor.execute (ProcessExecutor.java:906)
    at com.vaadin.flow.plugin.base.BuildFrontendUtil.runFrontendBuildTool (BuildFrontendUtil.java:486)
    at com.vaadin.flow.plugin.base.BuildFrontendUtil.runVite (BuildFrontendUtil.java:442)
    at com.vaadin.flow.plugin.base.BuildFrontendUtil.runFrontendBuild (BuildFrontendUtil.java:425)
    at com.vaadin.flow.plugin.maven.BuildFrontendMojo.execute (BuildFrontendMojo.java:138)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:126)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:328)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:316)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:174)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.access$000 (MojoExecutor.java:75)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor$1.run (MojoExecutor.java:162)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.execute (DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.java:39)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:159)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:73)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:118)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:261)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:173)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:906)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:283)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:206)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:568)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:283)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:226)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:407)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:348)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:47)
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
[DEBUG] Shutting down adapter factory; available factories [file-lock, rwlock-local, semaphore-local, noop]; available name mappers [discriminating, file-gav, file-hgav, file-static, gav, static]
[DEBUG] Shutting down 'file-lock' factory
[DEBUG] Shutting down 'rwlock-local' factory
[DEBUG] Shutting down 'semaphore-local' factory
[DEBUG] Shutting down 'noop' factory

Process finished with exit code 1
```

My project pom file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <!-- Project from https://start.vaadin.com/project/2a77899d-4228-4a19-9509-dc4b12c486ad -->
    <groupId>de.lange.pverein</groupId>
    <artifactId>pverein</artifactId>
    <name>pverein</name>
    <version>0.2.6-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <vaadin.version>24.3.2</vaadin.version>
        <selenium.version>4.8.1</selenium.version>
        <fullcalendar.version>6.0.4</fullcalendar.version>
        <fullcalendar.scheduler.version>6.0.4</fullcalendar.scheduler.version>
    </properties>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
    </parent>

    <repositories>
        <!-- The order of definitions matters. Explicitly defining central here to make sure it has the highest priority. -->

        <!-- Main Maven repository -->
        <repository>
            <id>central</id>
            <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>vaadin-prereleases</id>
            <url>
                https://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-prereleases/
            </url>
        </repository>
        <!-- Repository used by many Vaadin add-ons -->
        <repository>
            <id>Vaadin Directory</id>
            <url>https://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <!-- The order of definitions matters. Explicitly defining central here to make sure it has the highest priority. -->
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>central</id>
            <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>vaadin-prereleases</id>
            <url>
                https://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-prereleases/
            </url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <!-- Replace artifactId with vaadin-core to use only free components -->
            <artifactId>vaadin</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!--Kalender-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.vaadin.stefan</groupId>
            <artifactId>fullcalendar2</artifactId>
            <version>${fullcalendar.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.vaadin.stefan</groupId>
            <artifactId>fullcalendar2-scheduler</artifactId>
            <version>${fullcalendar.scheduler.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--Datenbanktreiber-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>8.2.0.jre8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!--Bildkonvertierung-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.coobird</groupId>
            <artifactId>thumbnailator</artifactId>
            <version>0.4.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-testbench</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!--Lombok dependencies (So kann getter and Setter in Entity entfallen-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!--Mail dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!--kartendarstelung dependencies
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>leaflet4vaadin</artifactId>
            <version>0.5.0</version>
        </dependency>-->
        <!-- JasperReports-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
            <version>6.20.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- JasperReports UI-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.vaadin.reportui</groupId>
            <artifactId>report-ui</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- File Downloader-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.vaadin.olli</groupId>
            <artifactId>file-download-wrapper</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--PWA dependencies CHAT -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!--spring admin tools dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!--Web Push -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>nl.martijndwars</groupId>
            <artifactId>web-push</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
            <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
            <version>1.69</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Include JUnit 4 support for TestBench and others -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
            <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <defaultGoal>spring-boot:run</defaultGoal>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <!-- Clean build and startup time for Vaadin apps sometimes may exceed
                     the default Spring Boot's 30sec timeout.  -->
                <configuration>
                    <jvmArguments>-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5557</jvmArguments>
                    <wait>500</wait>
                    <maxAttempts>240</maxAttempts>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-frontend</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <!-- Production mode is activated using -Pproduction -->
            <id>production</id>
            <dependencies>
                <!-- Exclude development dependencies from production -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                    <artifactId>vaadin-core</artifactId>
                    <exclusions>
                        <exclusion>
                            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                            <artifactId>vaadin-dev</artifactId>
                        </exclusion>
                    </exclusions>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                        <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>build-frontend</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <phase>compile</phase>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>

        <profile>
            <id>it</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>start-spring-boot</id>
                                <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>start</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                            <execution>
                                <id>stop-spring-boot</id>
                                <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>stop</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>

                    <!-- Runs the integration tests (*IT) after the server is started -->
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>integration-test</goal>
                                    <goal>verify</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                        <configuration>
                            <trimStackTrace>false</trimStackTrace>
                            <enableAssertions>true</enableAssertions>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>

    </profiles>
</project>
```

I deleted the node_modules folder and the json files: package.json and package-lock.json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This component, vcf-nav, is not compatible with vaadin 24.3. Take a look: https://github.com/vaadin/vcf-nav/issues/33. And a comment from the issue: Recommended action is to use SideNav component instead.

Documentation of SideNav component: https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/components/side-nav

Answer (score 0):

I replaced the following code in the MainLayout:

```
AppNav nav = new AppNav();
    if (accessChecker.hasAccess(DashboardView.class)) {
            nav.addItem(new AppNavItem("Dashboard", DashboardView.class, "la la-home"));
    }
```

To

```
SideNav nav = new SideNav();
    if (accessChecker.hasAccess(DashboardView.class)) {
            nav.addItem(new SideNavItem("Dashboard", DashboardView.class, VaadinIcon.DASHBOARD.create()));
    }
```